# og:url ignored in SPA when redirected to a route handling the rendering of required meta tags

Tags: javascript, express, single-page-application, meta-tags, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to implement social share buttons in my SPA that's served over Azure CDN.

In order overcome the problem of bots not executing javascript on my page I'm redirecting these (via 302) to my express.js backend where I'm rendering and returning valid HTML with all the required og: META tags populated, **all works just fine**.

```
<head>
  <meta property="og:title" content="${story?.headline}" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="${introText}" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://backend-example.com/${imageUrl}" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/story/${story?.id}" />
</head>
```

The problem is, the og:url tag is ignored in the thumbnail rendered by social networds, and istead of:

> "https://www.example.com/story/11"

it shows the URL of my backend:

> "https://www.backend-example.com/story/11"

I'm wondering if there's a possible workaround for this so the thumbnail will show the SPA's URL instead of the backends?

Best,
vedtam